# how to drawing a modular graph in explicit form?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-drawing

I used from networkx package in python for drawing a network. my network has a modular structure[image: fig1(b)]

i write a code that generate this adjacency matrix but when i draw my generating graph with networkx package, this figure is obtained.
[image: fig2]

and its modular structure isn't showed explicit(in particular in high order fig1c)
is there any suggestion tools(other software, specific package, ...) for drawing this graph for this purpose(modular structure)?

Comment: You can specify explicit positions for nodes using the `pos` parameter.